# How can I find my Apple ID on my iPad?

Tags: ipad, apple-id

My mum can't find her apple ID on her iPad. I'm not with her at the moment and do not have an iPad so I don't know where to look.

She already has an Apple ID set up on this iPad, so I don't want to set up another one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first option should be the most reliable:

1. Open Settings.app, scroll down and tap on "iTunes & App Stores". The Apple ID that the device is currently signed into will be at the top of the screen next to "Apple ID".

Alternate methods (only on iOS 5 or newer):

1. Settings.app > iCloud (under "Account")
2. Settings.app > Messages > Send & Receive At (under "Apple ID")
3. Settings.app > Facetime (under "Apple ID")